# Object state returning null values even though values have been changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a class called Form Controller where I manage the state of a specific form on my website.

Within this class I am able to load initial values which are values gathered from an API and automatically filled into the appropriate form fields. Also features state change on input change and retrieving the state and initial state (for comparison of changes).

Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Handles input forms with state management and HTML object data dissection. 
 */
export class FormController {
    initialState = {};
    state = {};

    /**
     * @param intialState Object with decided keys pre-established. Used to assign object key structure. Assigned values irrelevant as will be over-written.
     * @param initialValuesObject Object with pre-defined values. Inserts values into first paramter object if
     * they share keys.
     */
    constructor(initialStateStructure, initialStateValuesObject){
        this.loadInitialValues = this.loadInitialValues.bind(this);
        this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this);
        this.returnState = this.returnState.bind(this);
        this.returnInitialState = this.returnInitialState.bind(this);
        this.resetFormToInitialState = this.resetFormToInitialState.bind(this);

        this.initialState = initialStateStructure;
        this.loadInitialValues(initialStateValuesObject);
    }

    /**
     * Inserts values into common state object keys. 
     * @param initialValuesObject 
     */
    loadInitialValues(initialStateValuesObject){
        try {
            for (let key in initialStateValuesObject){
                if (this.initialState.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                    this.initialState[key] = initialStateValuesObject[key];
                }
            }
            // State and initialState start the same.
            this.state = this.initialState;
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    inputChange(event){
        event.persist();
        try {
            if (this.state.hasOwnProperty(event.target.name)){
                this.state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
            } else {
                console.log("Input attribute mismatch. Cannot find attribute: " + event.target.name);
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    returnState(event?){
        {event && event.preventDefault()}
        return this.state;
    }

    returnInitialState(){
        return this.initialState;
    }

    resetFormToInitialState(){
        this.state = this.initialState;
    }

}
```

The problem arises when I attempt to return initial state or state. When I console.log(this.state / initialstate), in the browser console, in the summary of the object I can see the new values that I've entered, but once I expand the log, all the values are at their initial state.

Returning the object outside always lands it at initial state. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Don't do `this.state = this.initialState;`. As your comment aptly states, this sets both properties to the *same* object, and they can no longer be mutated independently.

Comment: That's a critical error I've made. How would I assign the values of initialState to state without binding the properties to the same object?

Comment: Something like `Object.assign(this.state, this.initialState)`?

Comment: Can you please write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved :D. Thank you!